# How to delete Command Line Tools while keeping Xcode?

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode

I recently purchased a new Mac and I am currently in the process of setting it up as a development machine.

Before installing Xcode I went ahead and installed:

- Sublime Text
- Sublime Merge

While setting up Sublime Merge I was prompted to install the **Xcode Command Line Tools** (`Macintosh HD -> Library -> Developer -> Command Line Tools`).

I went ahead and did that, and was able to successfully set up my repos on Sublime Merge.

I then installed Xcode which comes bundled with the Command Line Tools in its own package (`Applications -> Xcode -> Contents -> Developer`).

Right after installing Xcode I saw that in Software Update I had an update to the Command Line Tools and so I performed that.

I'm striving for a clean set up and was wondering whether or not I now have redundant copies of the Command Line Tools, if so, ***how do I (or do I even need to) get rid of the old tools safely?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode.app provides a set of command line tools. Standalone 'Xcode Command Line Tools' provides another set. You can switch between them (see `xcode-select --help`).

`git`, `gcc` and many commands in `/usr/bin/` is actually a jumper to the real executable of selected CLT.

Standalone CLT is almost unnecessary if you have Xcode.app installed. You can simply trash `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` to remove it.

In my case it installed these pkg (`pkgutil --pkgs` before and after installation)

```
com.apple.pkg.DevSDK_macOS1013_Public
com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
com.apple.pkg.DevSDK
com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_macOSSDK
com.apple.pkg.macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14
com.apple.pkg.DevSDK_OSX109
com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_macOS1013
com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_macOS1014
com.apple.pkg.DevSDK_OSX1012
com.apple.pkg.DevSDK_OSX1011
com.apple.pkg.DevSDK_OSX1010
```

You can use `pkgutil --files <pkg_name>` to see installed files. They are either in `/tmp` or `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

---

However,

- `brew` sometimes requires you to install standalone CLT even you have Xcode.app installed, namely `python`. They say some bottles (pre-built) are linked against the standalone CLT.
- `brew` also requires standalone CLT when I want to build something on non-current system (Mojave after Catalina released).

Of course, you can take the risk and edit the brew formula or brew itself to avoid that.

`brew edit python`

```
  # setuptools remembers the build flags python is built with and uses them to                                          
  # build packages later. Xcode-only systems need different flags.                                                      
  pour_bottle? do
    reason <<~EOS                                                                                                       
      The bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.                                                    
        You can install them, if desired, with:                                                                         
          xcode-select --install                                                                                        
    EOS                                                                                                                 
    satisfy { MacOS::CLT.installed? } # comment this out
  end
```

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb:

```
      def needs_clt_installed?
        return false # <- add this
        return false if latest_sdk_version?

        without_clt?
      end
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and detailed answer, this clears things up quite a bit.